# value ! is not a member of akka.routing.Router

Tags: scala, akka

I've been working on getting some Akka examples up and running and have run into an issue that is giving me quite a bit of trouble. What's so strange to me is that there is code coming straight out of the documentation that isn't working.

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.routing.{ ActorRefRoutee, RoundRobinRoutingLogic, Router, Broadcast }


object TransformationManager {
  case class ProcessFile(fileIt:Iterator[String])
  case class ProcessLines(lines:List[List[String]], last:Boolean = false)
  case class LinesProcessed(lines:List[List[String]], last:Boolean = false)

  case object WorkAvailable
  case object WorkRequest
}

class TransformationManager extends Actor {
  import TransformationManager._

  val workChunkSize = 10
  val workersCount = 10

 def receive = {
   case ProcessFile(fileIt) => 
   var router = {
    val routees = Vector.fill(workersCount) {
      val r = context.actorOf(Props[SampleWorker])
      context watch r
      ActorRefRoutee(r)
    }
    Router(RoundRobinRoutingLogic(), routees)
   }
   router ! Broadcast(WorkAvailable) //error here !!!!!!!!!
 }
}
```

On the last line of code,

```
router ! Broadcast(WorkAvailable)
```

I get the error,

```
value ! is not a member of akka.routing.Router
```

I'm at a loss for why this isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `!` on `Router`.  You use `router.route` to send a message.

```
router.route(msg, sender())
```

Comment: In section 3.6.4 of the Akka documentation they provide an example of a Broadcast message being sent to a router so as to send a message to all routees at once. Were they incorrect in their code? [example](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.14/AkkaScala.pdf?_ga=1.146495732.1939526267.1440081025)

Comment: This worked for me when I put the Broadcast in the msg by the way, much appreciated. Strange that the docs have incorrect code. I guess it's just deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Referring to docs router could be an actor and then `!` should work, but it doesn't have to be, depends how you create it. Read more here:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html#A_Router_Actor