# Akka: How to broadcast messages to actors joined in a router using scala

Tags: scala, routes, akka, broadcast

In my application, I'd like to broadcast a time unit every 2 sec to all actors instances of Worker. The time unit is sent by the master to all the workers.
I am trying to send a broadcast message to all workers by the master actor, but it doesn't work with me. I attach my test code here. There is a compile error in the line

```
router ! Broadcast("any message") 
"Error: value is not a member of `akka.routing.Router`.
```

Could anyone tell me what is the problem here even I defined the router as an akka.routing.Router variable. Also, How can I broadcast this time_unit message every 2 sec?
Is it logically accepted to broadcast messages to local actors via routers?
Can I broadcast a message to every actor with different types that I defined in my application without specifying its type or even joined in a specific router.

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.routing.{ ActorRefRoutee, RoundRobinRoutingLogic, Router }
import akka.routing.Broadcast
import akka.routing.RouterActor

object Messages{
 object Work
 object Terminated
 object Time_Unit
}

object MainRouterDriver extends App {
  import Messages._

  val system = ActorSystem("HelloSystem")
  val routingMaster = system.actorOf(Props[Master], name = "helloactor")
  routingMaster ! Work

}

class Worker extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case _ =>
        println("Hi I am a Worker")
  }
}

class Master extends Actor {
  import Messages._
  var router = {
    val routees = Vector.fill(5) {
      val r = context.actorOf(Props[Worker])
      context watch r
      ActorRefRoutee(r)
    }
    akka.routing.Router(RoundRobinRoutingLogic(), routees)
  }
  def receive = {
    case Work =>
            router ! Broadcast(Time_Unit) 

  }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `BroadcastRoutingLogic` instead of round robin? That [works for me](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/simulator/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/simulator/Simulator.java).

Comment: Hi Manar, please don't cross post or explicitly say that you are doing so, to avoid double work answering questions. Thanks. (Same question on akka mailing list: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/akka-user/y0hVf6fq58M/3hWy0bn2EgAJ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
router.route(msg, sender())
```

It must work.! Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748412/value-is-not-a-member-of-akka-routing-router)

Comment: It means that there is no way to send message to all the routees that belong to that router except by looping all the routees and apply the route method as you did and as @Ben did in his broadcasting method.